# Pivot to produce Matrix like output without aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three tables.

PeriodTable (Always last 4 year)

```
**ID   Year**  
1     2016      
2     2017  
3     2018  
4     2019
```

StatusTable (Always four status)

```
**ID   Status**  
1     Completed      
2     Open  
3     New  
4     Declained
```

TransactionTable

```
**Year  AccountName  TotalAmount    Status**    
2019    King         1000000.00     Declained   
2019    BlueBird     3800000.00     Completed      
2018    Heartly Inc  250000.00      Open        
2016    ABB Data     1500000.00     Completed       
2016    Delta        500000.00      Declained
```

Expected Output:
Total no. of status from TransactionTable * 4 years. In this case 20 rows.

```
**Year  AccountName  TotalAmount    Status**    
2019    King         1000000.00     Declained   
2019    BlueBird     3800000.00     Completed
2019    NULL            NULL        Open        
2019    NULL            NULL        Completed       
2019    NULL            NULL        Declained      
2018    NULL            NULL        Declained   
2018    NULL            NULL        Completed      
2018    Heartly Inc  250000.00      Open        
2018    NULL            NULL        Completed       
2018    NULL            NULL        Declained
2017    NULL            NULL        Declained   
2017    NULL            NULL        Completed      
2017    NULL            NULL        Open        
2017    NULL            NULL        Completed       
2017    NULL            NULL        Declained
2016    NULL            NULL        Declained   
2016    NULL            NULL        Completed      
2016    NULL            NULL        Open        
2016    ABB Data     1500000.00     Completed       
2016    Delta        500000.00      Declained
```

I tried many solution from google but nothing worked out for me. 
Is it possible to achieve through pivot function since I do not need aggregate option here.

Comment: please share your current query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
select 
    p.Year, 
    case when p.Year <> t.Year then null else t.AccountName end as AccountName, 
    case when p.Year <> t.Year then null else t.TotalAmount end as TotalAmount, 
    t.Status
from #period as p
cross join #trans as t
order by p.Year desc
```

You could test it at [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12383d/1)